# Missing Permissions when using bulkDelete() on the bot's own messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to implement a command to delete the bot's N last messages in a channel. The bot does not have `MANAGE_MESSAGES` permission. When N = 1, the bot deletes its latest message, as intended. However, when N > 1, the bot throw the error:

```
D:\Seneca\7th_Term\DPS909\EarTensifier\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:170
          return reject(new DiscordAPIError(request.path, data, request.method, res.status));
                        ^

DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
    at RequestHandler.execute (D:\Seneca\7th_Term\DPS909\EarTensifier\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:170:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {      
  method: 'post',
  path: '/channels/757408200973877277/messages/bulk-delete',
  code: 50013,
  httpStatus: 403
}
```

What is weird to me is that how come the bot be able to delete 1 of its message, but not more? When I tested the same code with `MANAGE_MESSAGES` enabled, it works perfectly. Is it possible to implement this functionality without the `MANAGE_MESSAGES` permission, since I only want the bot to delete its own messages, not others'?

Here is my implementation:

```
const botID = process.env.DISCORD_ID;
if (message.channel.type == 'text') {
    await message.channel.messages.fetch({limit: 100}).then(messages => {
        let botMessages = messages.filter(msg => msg.author == botID).array();
        if (no_of_messages > 0){
            botMessages.splice(no_of_messages);
        }
        message.channel.bulkDelete(botMessages);
        client.log(`Deleted ${botMessages.length} messages from ${botID}`)
    }).catch(err => {
        client.log('Error while doing Bulk Delete');
        client.log(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#bulk-delete-messages
https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/26340acad946989e9a8825966b76c506d82fc641/src/structures/interfaces/TextBasedChannel.js#L303

Comment: Did you mean to put `msg.author.id` instead of `msg.author`?